# Sonata Admin - how to set the menu.label attribute?

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

According to the Sonata source code, the last node in the breadcrumb is rendered this way:

```
# standard_layout.html.twig #
<li class="active"><span>{{ menu.label }}</span></li>
```

In my setup, when opening a given Admin subclass, the last node simply becomes a raw string according to the entity handled by the Admin:

```
Dashboard  /  Entity List  /  Acme\SomeBundle\Entity\Stuff:000000001d74ac0a00007ff2930a326f
```

How can I set the value of menu.label to get something more appropriate? I have tried, in my Admin subclass, to override the following:

```
protected function configureTabMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null) {
    $this->configureSideMenu($menu, $action, $childAdmin);


}

protected function configureSideMenu(MenuItemInterface $menu, $action, AdminInterface $childAdmin = null) {
    $menu->setLabel("Some nice label");
    $menu->setName("Some nice name");
}
```

However, this does not change anything, even though I have verified that the methods above are called during runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a good (and somewhat obvious) solution to this.

The Sonata Admin class uses an internal toString($object) method in order to get a label string for the entity it is handling. Thus, the key is to implement the __toString() method of the entity in question:

```
public function __toString() {
    return "test";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to configure the `$classnameLabel` variable in the Admin Class :

```
class fooAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected $classnameLabel = 'Custom Label';
}
```

But it have the same issue (weird name with entity path) doing it, even if it is working fine on all the others pages.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the Sonata way of solving this is show here:

Quote:

> While it’s very friendly of the SonataAdminBundle to notify the admin of a successful creation, the classname and some sort of hash aren’t really nice to read. This is the default string representation of an object in the SonataAdminBundle. **You can change it by defining a toString() (note: no underscore prefix) method in the Admin class.** This receives the object to transform to a string as the first parameter:

Source: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/getting_started/the_form_view.html#creating-a-blog-post